# (Windows) Using ftello() returns incorrect file size for "some" binary files

Tags: c++, windows, filesize, fseek, ftell

I use `fseeko` to move the file pointer to the file end first, then use `ftello` to get the binary file size. I refer to this page [Do not use fseek...](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file) and follow exactly the same code in "Compliant Solution (POSIX ftello())" section.

My problem is this works fine for some binary file, but doesn't for some other binary files. I am now looking for a general way to access a binary file size.

```
fseeko(imageFile, 0, SEEK_END);
imageSize = ftello(imageFile);
fseeko(imageFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

I prefer to use stdio in C rather than any OS-based functions. Thanks!

Comment: Windows != POSIX

Comment: the `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` with `FileStandardInfo` or `NtQueryInformationFile` with `FileStandardInformation`. in both case (first is shell over second) in `EndOfFile` was size of file

Comment: what does `but doesn't for some other binary files` mean? Does one of the seeks fail, does the tello return the wrong value? Do the files have something in common? Are they over 2 Gigs in size or over 4?

Comment: or `GetFileSizeEx`

Comment: There are two examples of compliant Windows solutions there. Why did you decide to not use one of them and use a POSIX solution instead?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Oh, so I am using the wrong api calls?? Are fseeko() and ftello() for Linux and POSIX, I guess??

Comment: @RbMm I am trying not to use Windows API. I'd rather use stdio functions. Any idea??

Comment: @PeterT Sorry for being not clear about the problem. No ftello fails. Just the ftello returns incorrect values. One of the file is 15 GB and the other one is 2.5 GB. I have not found a common points yet. I'd like to know if the functions work for Windows first.

Comment: no, i know only winapi. i dont know stdio

Comment: @NeilButterworth by the way, why it works sometimes, for example, a 2.89 GB binary file??

Comment: @molbdnilo The reason that I use POSIX is because I do not want to use any OS-based functions and I presume the "Windows section" in that page is not using stdio functions. Feel free to tell me if there's some misunderstanding here. Thanks

Comment: The functions you are using are not part of Standard C or Standard C++, so you might as well use the Windows functions. Also, are you opening the file in binary mode?

Comment: @NeilButterworth So there's no stdio functions for calculating file sizes?? Yes, I am opening the files in binary mode

Comment: The standard library equivalents are fseek and ftell. There is no standard way in C of directly obtaining the size of a file. In C++ you could use the recently introduced filesystem library.

Comment: @NeilButterworth ha, so back to the question. Am I using the correct functions in a correct OS??

Comment: Note that `fseeko()` and `ftello()` use `off_t` values. "*On many architectures both `off_t` and `long` are 32-bit types, but compilation with
`#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` will turn `off_t` into a 64-bit type.*" A 32bit `off_t` can't handle file sizes > 2GB

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nice information, but I am still confused. Even as a 32-bit data type, off_t should be able to hold up to the number, 2,147,483,647. Why it can only handle less than 2097152(2GB)??

Comment: @Nick_Chang you said: "*One of the file is 15 GB and the other one is **2.5 GB**.*" - **Neither** of those values (`16,106,127,360`, `2,684,354,560`) will fit in a 32bit `off_t`. `2,097,152` is 2 **MB**, not 2 **GB** (`2,147,483,648`).